# Spring @Scheduled defaut value

Tags: java, spring, properties

I'm using a PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to get java properties in Spring scheduled annotation configuration

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${execution.frequency}")
public void generateReport() {
```

Is there a way to specify a default value when there isn't an overriding property value defined?

Spring 3 supports ${my.property:defaultValue} syntax, but isn't allowed on the annotation, I tried to pass variable but isn't allowed too, the value for annotation attribute Scheduled.cron must be a constant expression

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This syntax works for me

```
@Scheduled(cron = "${execution.frequency:0 */30 * * * ?}")
public void generateReport() {
```

all you need is to fix the default cron expression to your needs